# Asp.net Web Setup Project - Get selected hostname for Installer class

Tags: asp.net, installation

I have an installer class which I use to do some processing on the application after it is initially installed.

In the installer I have a custom dialog which requests a username and password. This is accessed in my installer class with

```
Me.Context.Parameters("username")
```

After setting it as CustomActionData `/username="[TXTUSERNAME]"`

This is all fine. The first dialog of a Web Setup Project gets the user to select an IIS website from a dropdownlist and set a VirtualDirectory if required. I need to get the seleted Hostname but so far I have failed to find a reference to it in any documentation.

I have tried things like:

```
Me.Context.Parameters("targetURL")
Me.Context.Parameters("TARGETSITE")
```

but none of them output anything..

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean you want to find a URL that resolves to the machine that the installer is currently running on? Or do you need to find the name of the machine so you can construct a URL e.g. http://myserver:8080/mySite/myVDir ?

Comment: In a Web Setup Project, under CustomActionData there are a range of Parameters that you can get access to in your custom installer class. For example I have a custom dialog with 2 textboxes and I use these to get the users Username and password. I can access them in my installer class using Me.Context.Parameters("username").

In a Web Setup Project you install the application into an IIS website. So where the IIS website you choose is pointing (directory wise) it will install it to that path. I want the hostname of the chosen IIS website so I can do some convenient setup at install time.

Comment: According to the documentation it should be something like: Me.Context.Parameters("targetURL") and /targetURL="[TARGETURL]" but it never works for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is it some proessing after installation or not? You said that it was in your the question (first line) so we assume that there is something runnable on disk :-)

For example, if you are deriving from System.Configuration.Install.Installer you can invoke it post install via installutil and pass any kind of args you want - meaning you are free from MSI at that point.

Also check out this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/command_lines_setups.aspx There's source code etc. showing how to pass completely arbitrary command line args to MSI.  It also lists tons of properties that are available - got to like at least one of them :-)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help this is the closest to the answer. That link looks really interesting.. 

My custom installer class is run at the commit stage, so before the MSI has totally finished but most of the install routine like copying files has been completed. I think this is just the normal time to invoke an installer class. 

At this stage I haven't been able to get the Hostname value from the IIS website "TARGETURL" etc.. this has given me a good link to go on.. Unfortunately I've been moved on to something else for the time being.. 

Again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
```

or

```
Response.Write(Request.Url.Host.ToString()
```

I don't know if this you are looking for..

Comment: Nope this is for the installer of my web application using a web setup project. The application hasn't even be installed into the IIS website at this point..

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample Web Setup project and opened the MSI in ORCA editor.

May be "`TARGETVDIR`" could be of any use